# MATLAB bar function examples do not work

Tags: matlab

I was having an issue with the `bar` function, where it would return either the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" or "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

To make sure everything was running okay, I copied and pasted one of the examples from "help bar" and entered it:

```
subplot(3,1,2), bar(0:.25:1,rand(5),1)
```

and I get the following response from MATLAB:

```
Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when
used as index 
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.
```

Now, I'm not really sure where to go from here short of completely reinstalling MATLAB.

Any suggestions? I've already tried restarting MATLAB/rebooting my computer.

Thanks!

EDIT: When I first start MATLAB, the bar function example works correctly. 
Then, after I import old data, the example bar function no longer works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing a variable called `bar`, so that when you run `bar(0:.25:1,rand(5),1)`, it thinks you are *indexing* the variable `bar` rather than providing an *input argument* to a function called `bar`.

Run `whos bar` to see the variable.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me haha, that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @MattBeardsley It happens, no sweat! :)